# scala regex group matching and replace

Tags: regex, scala, replace, regex-group

```
val REGEX_OPEN_CURLY_BRACE = """\{""".r
val REGEX_CLOSED_CURLY_BRACE = """\}""".r
val REGEX_INLINE_DOUBLE_QUOTES = """\\\"""".r
val REGEX_NEW_LINE = """\\\n""".r

// Replacing { with '{' and } with '}'
str = REGEX_OPEN_CURLY_BRACE.replaceAllIn(str, """'{'""")
str = REGEX_CLOSED_CURLY_BRACE.replaceAllIn(str, """'}'""")
// Escape \" with '\"' and \n with '\n'
str = REGEX_INLINE_DOUBLE_QUOTES.replaceAllIn(str, """'\"'""")
str = REGEX_NEW_LINE.replaceAllIn(str, """'\n'""")
```

Is there a simpler way to group and replace all of these `{,},\",\n`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use parenthesis to create a capture group, and `$1` to refer to that capture group in the replacing string:

```
"""hello { \" world \" } \n""".replaceAll("""([{}]|\\["n])""", "'$1'")
// => java.lang.String = hello '{' '\"' world '\"' '}' '\n'
```

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you wanted to do with the quotes, but I think this is what you were going for now...

Comment: And with fewer back slashes: """{ " \n }""".replaceAll("""(["{}\\n])""", "'$1'")

Comment: @yakshaver - Your example replaces `n` and `\ ` separately, e.g. `"no"` => `"'n'o"`. As for the backslash in front of the quotation mark, that's why I said I wasn't sure what he wanted to do with the quotes. I think he might actually be looking for `\"` rather than just `"` on its own.

Comment: You're right. How about this: "{ \" \n }".replaceAll("""(["{}\n])""", "'$1'")

Comment: @yakshaver - Now it replaces an actual newline instead of the sequence of characters _backslash n_.

Answer (score 16):

You can use regex groups like so:

```
scala> """([abc])""".r.replaceAllIn("a b c d e", """'$1'""")
res12: String = 'a' 'b' 'c' d e
```

The brackets in the regex allows you to match one of the characters between them. `$1` is replaced by whatever is found between the parentheses in the regular expressions.

Comment: Since his sequences are multicharacter(sometimes), I think alternation would work better.

Comment: `$0` is actually bound to the entire matching string. `$1` is bound to the first match group. In this case they happen to be the same though since the first match group encompasses the whole pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this is your string :

```
var actualString = "Hi {  {  { string in curly brace }  }   } now quoted string :  \" this \" now next line \\\n second line text"
```

Solution :

```
var replacedString = Seq("\\{" -> "'{'", "\\}" -> "'}'", "\"" -> "'\"'", "\\\n" -> "'\\\n'").foldLeft(actualString) { _.replaceAll _ tupled (_) }

scala> var actualString = "Hi {  {  { string in curly brace }  }   } now quoted string :  \" this \" now next line \\\n second line text"
actualString: String =
Hi {  {  { string in curly brace }  }   } now quoted string :  " this " now next line \
 second line text

scala>      var replacedString = Seq("\\{" -> "'{'", "\\}" -> "'}'", "\"" -> "'\"'", "\\\n" -> "'\\\n'").foldLeft(actualString) { _.replaceAll _ tupled (_) }
replacedString: String =
Hi '{'  '{'  '{' string in curly brace '}'  '}'   '}' now quoted string :  '"' this '"' now next line \'
' second line text
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: With a question this old it helps if you point out what your answer provides that the other answers don't.